# Specifying custom ordering of M2M relations in a FieldPanel for snippet-registered plain models

Tags: wagtail

We have a Django/DRF app with a product class that gets added into wagtail as a snippet so editors don't need to use two administration interfaces:

```py
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, ...

@register_snippet
class Product(ClusterableModel):
    ...

    related_products = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        related_name='related_product',
        blank=True,
        symmetrical=False
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

In order to pick related products in the admin interface, the `related_products` field is presented using a `FieldPanel`:

```py
@register_snippet
class Product(ClusterableModel):
    ...

    panels = [
        ...
        FieldPanel('related_products'),
        ...
    ]
    ...
```

However, there does not appear to be a way to specify a custom ordering for items purely for admin purposes, e.g. by adding an `ordering` to the `FieldPanel`. The docs do mention that snippets are not orderable in the same way `Page` is, but I'm not looking to allow editor-controled ordering in this case, just a predefined custom ordering inside the multi-select box that the FieldPanel ends up generating on the admin page.

I also can't find any hook that might be useful here, so: is it even possible to use a custom order *only* for panels?

Both template code (`{% for product in products %}`) and the snippet listing in the admin should use the `Meta`-specified ordering, but the FieldPanel for `related_products` when viewing/editing an individual product snippet should use different ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the ordering shown in the editor by passing a `queryset` argument to the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` used in the edit form. Normally form field objects are handled internally by the `FieldPanel`, but you can access them by [overriding the generated form](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms). In this case, this would be done as follows:

```py
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminModelForm


@register_snippet
class Product(ClusterableModel):
    # ... include field / panel definitions as normal


class ProductForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    related_products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Product.objects.order_by('some_field'),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,  # omit this for a multiselect box instead of checkboxes
        required=False
    )


Product.base_form_class = ProductForm
```

Comment: Answer fixed - hopefully setting base_form_class at the end of the definition should fix the circular dependency.